# Remove from onhold the question

Tags: discussion, status-completed

At first the question [Is it true that Hazrat Fatima (R.A) soul was taken by ALLAH Himself](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14960/4510) 
was on hold mainly due to question asked in Urdu language and was unclear. As i have edited and translated into English i would like the moderators to kindly open the question as i too have interest to know its answer.

If it is still unclear kindly comment it so i can make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this has been reviewed and taken care of. The question is open on main now so no further meta discussion is needed unless someone thinks the re-open was in error and it should be closed.

Comment: I apparently missed the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag when browsing from mobile, sorry for the slightly redundant attempt to wrap this question up.